# xml parsing of a soap envelope using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm starting out parsing XML in C# using XmlDocument. I've following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getCustomersResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace">
            <getCustomersReturn soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[2]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <getCustomersReturn xsi:type="soapenc:string"></getCustomersReturn>
                <getCustomersReturn xsi:type="soapenc:string">some data</getCustomersReturn>
                <getCustomersReturn xsi:type="soapenc:string">some more data</getCustomersReturn>
            </getCustomersReturn>
        </ns1:getCustomersResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(result);  //loading soap message as string
XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://DefaultNamespace"); 

XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn", xmlNamespaceManager);

string[] results = new string[xmlNodeList.Count];

var str = "";
var count = 0;
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
{
    str += xmlNode.InnerText;
}

Assert.IsNull(results, xmlNodeList.Count + ", " + count + ", " + str);
```

I want to retrieve the child nodes (text) of `getCustomersReturn` as a `string[]`

**Problem:**

All the nodes are getting flattened into a single string instead of an array.

`xmlNodeList.Count` is coming as 1 instead of 3

Edit: subsequent problems after implementing the answers

```
CS1061  'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: can someone suggest or advise instead of voting, so I know what's wrong with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one change in your code.
Replace the line :

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn", xmlNamespaceManager);
```

with the below line

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn/getCustomersReturn", xmlNamespaceManager);
```

Use the below code it will give you the desired output

```
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(result);  //loading soap message as string
                XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

                xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://DefaultNamespace");

                XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn/getCustomersReturn", xmlNamespaceManager);

                string[] results = new string[xmlNodeList.Count];

                var str = "";
                var count = 0;
                foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
                {
                    str += xmlNode.InnerText;
                }

                Assert.IsNull(results, xmlNodeList.Count + ", " + count + ", " + str);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why I had to mention `getCustomersReturn` twice

Comment: yes getCustomersReturn is inside getCustomersReturn  in your xml body so it was needed to be mentioned twice

Comment: thanks for the explanation, is it possible to use string array instead of list while iterating? appreciate code edits.

Comment: the return type for  xmlDocument.SelectNodes is XmlNodeList so we need to use XmlNodeList
Let me know if you require more explanation

Comment: Thanks, the code works and it has been working in my unit tests, now I moved the code to my library class that was under test, and I came across `SelectNodes` errors, any idea? I mean same code worked fine within the unit tests but not working within the class file.

Comment: are you getting compilation error or run time error
if possible share your library class code

Comment: it's a compile time error, I edited my question to add details, there's a red line under `SelectNodes`, I've nugget XmlDocument 4.3.0 installed

Comment: is there a difference in nugget package, I looked up and found two, `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and the other is `System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument`, which one should I use? update: I tried `System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument` and code worked, these things confuse if we have two nugets with similar names

Comment: yes it confuses some time, the compile time error was namespace error
which is resolved now using System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument

Comment: can you please upvote the question, I don't know why some idiot had a problem

Answer (score 0):

Just using a `XPath` expression, this code is simple but can help you know what problem do you have. This link can help you understand `XPath` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

```
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xmlstring);
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://DefaultNamespace");
    //select all nodes using XPath
    var search = xml.SelectNodes("//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn//getCustomersReturn",manager);
    //saving XmlNodeList to List<string>
    var r = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode item in search)
        r.Add(item.InnerText);
    string[] ary = r.ToArray(); //convert List<string> to string[]
```

Comment: can you please explain why `getCustomersReturn` was repeated twice?

Comment: XML structure like a tree, if `XPath` expresstion is `//ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn` then just matching `getCustomersResponse/getCustomersReturn`, but in you xml file, `getCustomersResponse` has many `getCustomersResponse` children, so `XPath` must using '/ns1:getCustomersResponse/getCustomersResponse//getCustomersResponse'.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, last node has two forward slashes, any significance or is it a typo, also can you upvote it, I don't know why people are too eager to neg vote it, also is it possible to use string [] array instead of list while iterating, appreciate code edits

Comment: one forward slash means only one child, two forward slashed means all suitable children.this is `XPath expression` .But in here, there are same. **SEE MORE** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath